# issue with multisite SSR transfer state in Sparatcus 3.4

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using Sparatcus 3.4 upgraded from 2.0.we are using multiple sites(AU and NZ).

problem is when we access any site first (say AU) its giving me the data correctly and everything running fine but when I open the NZ site in the same tab or another tab (which have diff domain but same nginx server) its returning me the AU data. and when I checked the localStorage and sessionStorage for site id and currency its showing me the last website data (ie. AU). and then if I refresh the page its shows me the correct NZ data.

after debugging I found  there is issue with the state transfer, maybe server is returning the just last state from server.

Comment: hi guys, any update please ?

Comment: any update  on this please ?

Comment: issue covered in issue [another ssr issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69520981/ssr-issue-in-3-x-version)