# SSR issue in 3.x version

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Recently we did Spartacus upgrade from 2.0 to 3.4 version to fix the SSR issues which we were seeing in the earlier version of Spartacus. However, we are seeing one very serious issue in the SSR optimization with this upgrade identified only in the production environment, which we went live on 5th October 2021.

As per the documentation, Spartacus fallbacks to CSR (Content Side Rendering) if SSR is not able to render the page within certain period. In the background, the SSR server continues to render the SSR version of the page. Once this rendering finishes, the page is placed in a local cache to be returned the next time it is requested.

What’s happening now in production environment having explained what Spartacus is doing OOTB?

If User A is visiting the website [www.freedom.com.au](http://www.freedom.com.au) (AU site) and let’s say, Spartacus fallbacks to CSR as SSR was not able to render the page. Now if the same user or another user let’s say user B requests for [www.freedomfurniture.co.nz](http://www.freedomfurniture.co.nz) (NZ site) and if this request goes to the same node where page for AU site was cached, SSR will return AU rendered page even if user requested NZ site.

To fix this issue, we are using Rendering Strategy as ALWAYS_SSR so that it doesn’t fallback to CSR at all so that this cache doesn’t get generated, and customer doesn’t see this issue. Is this something right approach are we taking? Will this impact performance or will it be same as version 2.0 of Spartacus? We were able to replicate this issue easily in local dev box as there is only one node present and after this fix, it is not getting replicated.

Please let us know if it is not an issue and we are doing some wrong analysis around it.

Documentation link: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-optimization/

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for raising this issue, we will address it.

You're seeing this issue because the default `renderKeyResolver` function doesn't include the domain in the final key, making the requests to `https://example1.au/product/1` and `https://example2.com/product/1` the same. This means they are cached as the same key `/product/1`, and not as two different keys.

As a temporary workaround, you can do the following in your code:

- copy the following functions to your e.g. `server.ts`: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/setup-4.1.1/core-libs/setup/ssr/engine-decorator/ng-express-engine-decorator.ts#L85-L106
- provide a custom `renderKeyResolver` to the SSR optmization config:

```
const domainIncludedRenderingKey = (req: Request): string => {
  return getRequestUrl(req); // the function you copied from our source code
};
```

*note*: to resolve the TS errors, make sure to import `Request` from `express`, if it's not already imported.