# Node Server Restart Issue

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Since go-live with Spartacus 2.0 in December last year, we are experiencing node server restart issue. After carefully analysing the code, we made some fixes which decreased the count of the restarts but not the full issue.

In September 2021, we upgraded the Spartacus framework from 2.0 to 3.4 version, but still this issue was there and could see 3 server restarts per day in one node. Within a week of going live with the 3.4 version, we encountered one serious issue where content was getting switched between our multi-sites.  Here is the link to the ticket raised for the same: [SSR issue in 3.x version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69520981/ssr-issue-in-3-x-version)

After carefully reading the Spartacus documentation, we gave a workaround in the rendering strategy to use ALWAYS_SSR and never fallback to CSR in case of timeout. This workaround surprisingly fixed the server restart issue as well. But now, with our recent release in November 2021, we did put the SAP suggested workaround to solve the issue being raised in [SSR issue in 3.x version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69520981/ssr-issue-in-3-x-version), which got resolved, however, opens the server restart issue again in production.

I highly suspect that when cache reaches some threshold, node server is getting restarted automatically, which was not happening when we were using the ALWAYS_SSR rendering strategy.

Can we please hear something on this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure you use the latest patch (3.4.5) and let us know if this problem still occurs with that.

Comment: @MichałGruca, Is this a known issue with the older versions/patch? I am checking with Angular team for the correct version though. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about a specific issue, but there is the probability that the problem has been solved in the newer patch. It's a good practice to always bump the package to the latest version of the patch (no breaking changes so no cost), then we are sure that the problem you are talking about has not been resolved yet.

Comment: One reason of node.js app restarting might be the `cacheSize` is set to too high value - in such case node restarts periodically because of insufficient RAM (because of storing the renders in RAM). Not sure what's your version of Spartacus but as @MichałGruca already mentioned there are some SSR improvements present in recent releases.
By changing the strategy to `ALWAYS_SSR` I believe you're not using the SSR cache at all because it always do the render (so no need to cache) - but pls double check that with Spartacus code (checkout to version you're using).

Comment: We are on Spartacus 3.3.1 version but still would like to see if there are any significant changes being introduced or not with the latest version. I will also check on the cacheSize part, but I guess it will same as OOTB. @MirosławGrochowski